Computer won't use the GPU to render when using cmd
I'm using K-Cycles. I've tried rendering a single frame from some small test projects with the command prompt and it works great, but when it comes to the big project I need to render it doesn't seem to work.
Rendering in GUI gives me an estimated 43 minutes and I can see the GPU running in the task manager, but if I execute the same project in cmd using:
blender --factory-startup -b "C:\Users\josia\OneDrive\Desktop\night_bounces\1.blend" -o //render_# -f 4

It estimates 17 hours, runs the CPU to 100% and then continues to add more and more time till completed. I know it might be hard to diagnose without the project file, but does any one have any ideas?

Hi. Please use proper code tags, when posting snippets

I’m guessing that —factory-startup is the issue. Why is it there?

Oh! Someone suggested it put that because I kept getting errors about it trying to load plugins I wasn't using but that werent installed correctly. Let me try without and report back, thanks!
